# Rewrite rule is not working properly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to write SEO friendly usls using Apache Mod-Rewrite.

My URLs are something like this.

```
index.php?p=edit-profile 
index.php?p=edit-profile&id=3 
index.php?p=edit-profile&id=3&city=sydney
index.php?p=edit-profile&id=3&city=sydney&name=some example text
```

This is how I tried it.

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&city=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&city=$3&name=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Here, first, second and third rules are working for me. But my problem is If I have a string with spaces for fourth variable my forth rule is not working. And also if I have a single word for forth one again it doesn't work.

Can anybody tell me how I fix this problem. Is there a way to replace these spaces with hyphens?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include space in your character class:

```
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&city=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\s\w-]+)/?$ index.php?p=$1&id=$2&city=$3&name=$4 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: Thank you. Can we replace space with hyphens?

Comment: It can be done but not a good idea. Your php code will get original string in `GET` array this way.

Comment: Understood.. Thanks for your time.

Comment: One more question... Can we hide first and second string from URL in fourth RULE?

Comment: No you will need `id` in your code for doing some database lookup.